# How to make a button that hits a link but does not navigate to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a server that monitors for HTTP activity, then triggers a local action.

From a remote device I currently use this to trigger my server:

```
<a href="http://example.org" onClick="return"><button type="button" style="width:100px;background-color:#43BC67">Try Me</button></a>
```

The only problem is, it navigates to a new page which shows the reply from the server which is "Done". I don't want to see that page or the reply. I just want to silently hit that URL. Ideas?

Thanks for everyone's help. This works when I load or reload the page, but not when I click the button. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
<button type="button"><iframe src="example.org" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>Test</button>
```

Comment: Do you have access to change the other page (the 'done' page)?

Comment: if you only want to get a http request you could also create an image,script or anything that would trigger a http request to your server with javascript and add it to the dom and remove it after it finished loading. The best choice is to create an ajax request though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an `ajax` call. You can get rid of the `a` tag and just write `javascript` code to make an `ajax` call to your url when the button is clicked.

[AJAX Calls](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

[More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Why would you downvote the correct answer. Say why you downvoted. A downvote without an explanation doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I ran into something like this once. Yes, AJAX is the best way to go, but keep in mind that if the url you need to hit is on another domain, you might run into problems with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). If you need a workaround for that, I might suggest using javascript to create a hidden `iframe` with that url as it's `src`

Comment: @brso05 it might be downvoted due to the lack of any real example.

Comment: @DaveZych Doesn't need an example. The user should be able to look up how to do an `AJAX` request. I also posted links. We don't always spoon feed code here we point someone in the right direction it is better if they can figure it out themselves that is a good way to learn.

Comment: @brso05 Right, it was just a guess of why it would be downvoted. However, link only answers, which this essentially is, should be avoided because links will eventually break and therefore render this answer more useless than it already is. It would be better to link to another SO answer, which is almost guaranteed to never break, or provide an example.

Comment: @DaveZych this isn't a link only answer it answers his question as to how he can accomplish his task. Make an AJAX call. If the links break (which I doubt they will `MDN` and `W3Schools` probably as much a chance as `Stackoverflow` links breaking) then it isn't hard to `Google` `javascript` and `AJAX` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. The ones that spring to mind, in my order of preference, are:

1. Link to a URL that returns a [`204 No Content` response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)
2. Use JavaScript and [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to make the request
3. Target the link to a hidden iframe
4. Use JavaScript to create an element which loads external content, such as an `img` and add it to the DOM.

Incidentally, you cannot have a button inside a link. If you want to submit a form use a button. If you want to link somewhere, then use a link. Apply CSS if you want your link to look like a button or your button to look like something else.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any possibility for you to use jquery then you can do this (when you click on the link it will prevent the browser from actually navigating to the url):

HTML:

```
<body>
    <a id="mylink" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#mylink").click(function(e){

        //prevent browser from navigating to the url
        e.preventDefault();

        //call url asynchronously (in other words call url in the background)
        $.get( "http://myserver/ping", function(data){

            //do something with the response

        });

    });

});
```

Hope it helps!